# mod_rewrite to change query data

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have two files in a folder called MyFolder: `index.php` and `members.php`
I specify the member in `members.php` like so

```
members.php?member=member1
```

I would rather just write something like this in the browser:

```
MyFolder/member1
```

`index.php` should be unaffected

What do I write in my `.htaccess` file to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /member.php?member=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [L]
```

You can put that in the "myfolder" folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/myfolder/(.*) /myfolder/member.php?member=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/myfolder/?$ /myfolder/index.php [L]
```

Comment: no if that is the case then u would use something like this in whatever folder is located before myfolder:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) /member.php?member=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [L]

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  It only changes the URL for anything I typ e to member.php